# Neovim setting up jdtls with lsp-zero/mason

Tags: java, neovim, eclipse-jdt

As part of the upcoming 2023 new year I wanted to try and move my development environment to vim or neovim. I have gone through a bit of setup already and have go and js/ts setup and appearing to work just fine. Autocomplete, linting and import management.

Trying to get lsp-zero and java working though is turning out to be a nightmare (because of course java would be a problem child). I opened a java file lsp-zero was baller and asked to install the `jdtls` which appears to have worked and voila nothing... I just have code highlighting. No auto-complete or importing management.

[image: Mason LSP Servers]

I added the following to test

```
-- configure an individual server
lsp.configure('jdtls', {
  flags = {
    debounce_text_changes = 150,
  },
  on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    print('lsp server (jdtls) attached')
  end
})

lsp.configure('gopls', {
  flags = {
    debounce_text_changes = 150,
  },
  on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    print('lsp server (gopls) attached')
  end
})
```

Java is not picking up the lsp server
[image]

Go picks up just fine
[image]

Does anyone know of additional configs that are needed. I am not seeing anything specifically called out.

--- Config edit ---

I updated the config to call the windows version of the scripts. I also added a data path and root_dir. The lsp still never triggers.

```
require'lspconfig'.jdtls.setup{
 cmd = {
        'jdtls-win.cmd',
        "-configuration",
        "C:\\Users\\Coury\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\mason\\packages\\jdtls\\config_win",
        "-jar",
        "C:\\Users\\Coury\\AppData\\Local\\nvim-data\\mason\\packages\\jdtls\\plugins\\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.400.v20210924-0641.jar",
        "-data",
        "C:\\Users\\Coury\\Documents\\Code\\interviews\\truleo\\app",
    },
    single_file_support = true,
    root_dir = function() 
        return "C:\\Users\\Coury\\Documents\\Code\\interviews\\truleo\\app"
    end,
    flags = {
        debounce_text_changes = 150,
    },
    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
        print('lsp server (jdtls) attached')
    end
}
```

Comment: The command `:LspLog` has info. Any errors?

LSP Zero (VonHeikemen/lsp-zero.nvim) uses mason.nvim (williamboman/mason.nvim) for managing LSP servers. Which has an extension (williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim) to work with (neovim/nvim-lspconfig). The doc/server_configurations.md#jdtls says `IMPORTANT: If you want all the features jdtls has to offer, nvim-jdtls is highly recommended. If all you need is diagnostics, completion, imports, gotos and formatting and some code actions you can keep reading here.` You should probably follow the setup here https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls.

Comment: Also, what version of Java are you running? 

eclipse.jdt.ls requires at least Java 17 (see https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls/blob/2773a6b2f6518c14bbbc2b8367d56a36db2889c4/README.md?plain=1#L69)

Comment: @Mike I am running 17. The important part is if I want the additional features and currently I do not. I just want what jdtls has to offer to see if it is practical to start moving my workflow over. `:LspLog` has nothing in it (I cleared it out for some config typos that I had earlier on). `LspInfo` shows that it seems to know that it should be jdtls but it has `root directory:    Not found.` Not sure what that means.

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set and exported? I have had issues where even though it appears correct, I'll explicitly `export JAVA_HOME="<yourhomehere>"` before opening neovim and it works.

Comment: @Mike I do indeed. I had a trailing slash that I never noticed but removing it did nothing for me.

Comment: I believe LSP log has nothing to do with your issue as I mentioned in the comments in the answer given by someone else, jdtls does not require attachment on your LSP. Just go modify the `ftplugin/java.lua` file. You can refer to my configurations (windows) https://github.com/Kuon-dev/dotfiles/blob/main/nvim/ftplugin/java.lua

Comment: @Remicaster it does but I am getting nothing in it. I am starting to think that jdtls is not starting.

Comment: There was a bug in the way that file paths were parsed on window https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/2341 newer versions of neovim do not appear to suffer from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, include java path to your `bashrc`. And retry the installation using `Mason.nvim`

Else: Do below

1. Install [eclipse.jdt.ls](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls) by following their [Installation instructions](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ls#installation).
2. Add the plugin:

- vim-plug: Plug `mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls`
- packer.nvim: use `mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls`

3. To solve this you'd have to create your personal jdlts config file in your plugins directory like so

```lua
-- Java.lua

local config = {
    cmd = {
        --
        "java", -- Or the absolute path '/path/to/java11_or_newer/bin/java'
        "-Declipse.application=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.id1",
        "-Dosgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4",
        "-Declipse.product=org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.product",
        "-Dlog.protocol=true",
        "-Dlog.level=ALL",
        "-Xms1g",
        "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM",
        "--add-opens",
        "java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED",
        "--add-opens",
        "java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED",
        --
        "-jar",
        "/path/to/jdtls_install_location/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_VERSION_NUMBER.jar",
        "-configuration", "/path/to/jdtls_install_location/config_SYSTEM",
        "-data", "/Users/YOUR_MACHINE_NAME/local/share/nvim/java"
    },
    settings = {
        java = {
            signatureHelp = {enabled = true},
            import = {enabled = true},
            rename = {enabled = true}
        }
    },
    init_options = {
        bundles = {}
    }
}
```

Source the new config and open any java file.

Comment: I am on a windows machine and Java is accessible via pwsh. I am using lsp-zero and would prefer to continue to use that tool it at all possible. It is a very nice wrapper for most of the tooling that is needed.

Comment: have you tried using the verbose config of jdtls yet? @nerdlyist

Comment: @Remicaster I can try that but I am not confident in where my configuration should go with lsp-zero. Where I currently have the simple setup is failing.

Comment: I was mistaken in my previous docs `nvim-jdtls` and `jdtls` are different and the latter is used.

Comment: jdtls has a different configuration compared to other LSP and from my experience it does not need attachment on your lsp config. Just follow the docs you sent and you should have no issues with it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls) to run and configure the language server.

Its simply a matter of setting up a FTPlugin for java that calls `jdtls.start_or_attach(jdtls_config)` whenever a java file/repo is opened which will start the language server and attach it to your buffer which can be verified by `:LspInfo`.

ftplugin/java.lua:

```
local jdtls_config = require("myconfig.lsp.jdtls").setup()
local pkg_status, jdtls = pcall(require,"jdtls")
if not pkg_status then
  vim.notify("unable to load nvim-jdtls", "error")
  return
end
jdtls.start_or_attach(jdtls_config)
```

and the corresponding config using jdtls (installed via mason)
You may want to provide your own capabilities and on_attach functions but otherwise it should give you a good nudge in the right direction.

myconfig/lsp/jdtls.lua

```
local opts = {
  cmd = {},
  settings = {
    java = {
      signatureHelp = { enabled = true },
      completion = {
        favoriteStaticMembers = {},
        filteredTypes = {
          -- "com.sun.*",
          -- "io.micrometer.shaded.*",
          -- "java.awt.*",
          -- "jdk.*",
          -- "sun.*",
        },
      },
      sources = {
        organizeImports = {
          starThreshold = 9999,
          staticStarThreshold = 9999,
        },
      },
      codeGeneration = {
        toString = {
          template = "${object.className}{${member.name()}=${member.value}, ${otherMembers}}",
        },
        useBlocks = true,
      },
      configuration = {
        runtimes = {
          {
            name = "JavaSE-1.8",
            path = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home",
            default = true,
          },
          {
            name = "JavaSE-17",
            path = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home",
          },
          {
            name = "JavaSE-19",
            path = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}

local function setup()
  local pkg_status, jdtls = pcall(require,"jdtls")
  if not pkg_status then
    vim.notify("unable to load nvim-jdtls", "error")
    return {}
  end

  -- local jdtls_path = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/mason/packages/jdtls"
  local jdtls_bin = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/mason/bin/jdtls"

  local root_markers = { ".gradle", "gradlew", ".git" }
  local root_dir = jdtls.setup.find_root(root_markers)
  local home = os.getenv("HOME")
  local project_name = vim.fn.fnamemodify(root_dir, ":p:h:t")
  local workspace_dir = home .. "/.cache/jdtls/workspace/" .. project_name

  opts.cmd = {
    jdtls_bin,
    "-data",
    workspace_dir,
  }


  local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
    jdtls.setup.add_commands() -- important to ensure you can update configs when build is updated
    -- if you setup DAP according to https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls#nvim-dap-configuration you can uncomment below
    -- jdtls.setup_dap({ hotcodereplace = "auto" })
    -- jdtls.dap.setup_dap_main_class_configs()

    -- you may want to also run your generic on_attach() function used by your LSP config
  end

  opts.on_attach = on_attach
  opts.capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()

  return opts
end

return { setup = setup }
```

These examples are yanked from my [personal neovim config](https://github.com/jaybocc2/dotfiles/pull/3) ([jdtls config](https://github.com/jaybocc2/dotfiles/blob/bf7828b91facf1b0a0e2e442f740cd66830b79ef/nvim/lua/lsp/settings/jdtls.lua)).  Hope this helps get you rolling.

Also make sure you have jdk17+ available for jdtls (i launch neovim with JAVA_HOME set to my jdk17 install)
(your code can still be compiled by and run on jdk8 -- I successfully work on gradle projects that are built with jdk8 no problems w/ this config)

Comment: Do you happen to have this running on windows or are you using linux/mac? I have tried all three os and the only one I am running into issues with in windows.

Comment: Unfortunately what little development i do on windows is usually with VSCode or visual studio.

Interesting that this works for you on mac/linux as i could not get jdtls to work without `jdtls.start_or_attach()` filetype plugin.

What does `:LspInfo` show you? It should show jdtls attached to the buffer (even if the process died).

If you don't see it attached to the buffer its most likely that you're not getting `jdtls.start_or_attach(config)` triggered to attach JDTLS to the buffer.

If you do see it attached but dead, you should take a look at `:LspLog` and share the output.

Comment: A thought, @nerdlyist do you have Python 3.9+ installed and available in the path? jdtls wrapper requires it but its not strongly called out.

Comment: You are correct that it is not called out on the python version but I did figure that out a little while back. I am updated there. As for the output I have an issue open here with those details https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/2341

Comment: As an fyi I have attempted to switch to `nvim-jdtls` and `nvim-lspconfig` direct with the same issue. I might be the only person using neo-vim for java on windows :(

Comment: @JayBoCC2 For the runtimes, are the paths that you supplied the binary directories? Like is java(.exe) in the Home directory for you?

Comment: @Shogery the proper version of `java` should be in your path, whether your on windows or *Nix/OSX in order to run JDTLS.  the `runtimes` map is used to specify the versions of java you need JDTLS to be able to code-complete for your projects

Comment: the dirs i have specified in runtimes is the java installation for the various versions of java... ie: contains bin/, jre/, lib/, include/ dirs